debug_traceTransaction on a full node not working
I'm running a full but not archive node using geth. I'm trying to get trace for a transaction using debug.traceTransaction('0x4883a2cd5a260723ae65b88787d153864938e0cf0b811bc0597a80e3e820777a'); but it returned me
Error: historical state not available in path scheme yet
at web3.js:6387:9(39)
at send (web3.js:5116:62(29))
at <eval>:1:23(3)

In my understanding, a full node will store a last 128 block's history so if the transaction is within the range it could re-execute it and return me the trace. This transaction is happen in block 10291816, and I'm currently syncing to block 10291818, so the history data should still not be pruned yet.
Anyone could let me know if there is anything wrong? Thank you in advance!!
